# Using Cypher, how to determine if one collection of relationships is fully contained in another collection of relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I will start out by explaining the current domain model.  In North America the car manufacturers produce collectively about 3500 distinct trims (Like a 2016 Ford F150 XLT Crew Cab Long Box, or 2016 Audi A3 4dr AWD quattro Sedan)

I have created a Neo4j graph where every trim for every year is a Node (with a label `:Vehicle`).  I also created a second set of nodes of type Feature (all nodes are labeled `:Feature`).  Feature nodes also have a second label that describes the type of feature ( like `:MDL`, `:DIV`, `:TRIM`, `:DRIVE`, etc.), and features have a value property. So, for the F150 listed above

```
VehicleId | FeatureType | FeatureValue
----------|-------------|-------------
"380333"  | "BOX"       | "regular"
"380333"  | "DIV"       | "Ford"
"380333"  | "TYPE"      | "Truck
"380333"  | "MDL"       | "F-150"
"380333"  | "CYLINDERS" | "V-8"
"380333"  | "TRIM"      | "XL"
etc...
```

All is good. Now, we have a second concept called FVD (short for Flexible Vehicle Description) which is a simple query syntax that describes a set of vehicles using features. For example, the following FVD (+COUNTRY=US+YR=2016+DIV=Mazda+TYPE=Sport Utility) says all US 2016 Mazda Sport Utilities. I have added FVD nodes to the database (with a label `:FVD`) with INCLUDES relationships to the same Feature Nodes described above.

Finally, my question is, Given that I START at a certain `:Vehicle` node, how do I find all `:FVD`'s whose `:Feature` nodes (through the `:INCLUDES` relationship) are ALL nodes that the :Vehicle node points to as well.   NOTE: The `:Vehicle` node could point to more features than the `:FVD` node.

If you are thinking, why not create a direct relationship between the `:FVD` and the `:Vehicle`. The reason is because the `:FVD` represents a Set, the vehicles that come in an out of the Set are dynamic throughout the year, which is why I am keeping this abstraction tier.

Sorry for the lengthy post, just trying to explain the situation.   I started to play with "Collect", but I got to the point where I had 2 collections, and I needed to know if one collection was completely in another collection.

Comment: Please show your current Cypher code in the question.

Comment: I tried the following query, but no success (this returned nothing).  I am assuming the WHERE clause with IN is not working.   MATCH (v:Vehicle{styleId:"380333"})--(vehFeature:Feature)
WITH collect(vehFeature) as vehFeatures
MATCH  (fvd:FVD)-[:INCLUDES]->(fvdFeature:Feature)
WITH fvd, vehFeatures, collect(fvdFeature) as fvdFeatures
WHERE fvdFeatures IN vehFeatures
RETURN fvd

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`all`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-all) list predicate. The `all` list predicate will tests whether a predicate holds for all elements of the list.

I *think* this will work for your example:

```
MATCH (v:Vehicle{styleId:"380333"})--(vehFeature:Feature) 
  WITH collect(vehFeature) as vehFeatures 
MATCH (fvd:FVD)-[:INCLUDES]->(fvdFeature:Feature) 
  WITH fvd, vehFeatures, collect(fvdFeature) as fvdFeatures 
  WHERE all(vf IN vehFeatures WHERE vf IN fvdFeatures)
RETURN fvd
```

Comment: Nice.   That worked once I made one change on your WHERE clause,  all(ff in vehFeatures WHERE ff in fvdFeatures)

Comment: oops - fixed the typo. Glad you caught that.